# CSVに書いたURLのスクショをSeleniumで撮影する方法

Tags: python, selenium

下記のページを参考に試してみたのですがうまくいきませんでした。

[CSVに書いたURLを順番に開いて全画面スクリーンショットを取るスクリプト - Qiita](https://qiita.com/YoshikiIto/items/42fb32fe9c88b7141708)

urls.csv内のURL情報を read_csv.py で読み込むのは成功。

しかし、test_screenshot.py 内の ChromeDriverManager というモジュールが自分のPCに無いらしくスクショを撮影できません。

**質問**

下記いずれかの方法についてご教授ください。

1. 上記コードで ChromeDriverManager を使用しない方法
2. anacondaに ChromeDriverManager を入れる方法

※参考
[Python+SeleniumWebDriverではwebdriver_managerを使うといちいちdriverのexeを置き換えなくて済む - Qiita](https://qiita.com/YoshikiIto/items/000f241f6d917178981c)

---

**構成**

```
.
├─ data
│　└─ urls.csv
│
├─ utilities
│　└─ read_csv.py
│
└─ test_screenshot.py
```

**test_screenshot.py**

```
import time

import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from utilities.read_csv import read_csv_data

class TestScreenshot():

datalist = read_csv_data("./data/urls.csv")

@classmethod
def setup_class(cls):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()

@pytest.mark.parametrize("id, url", datalist)
def test_reserve_multi(self, id, url):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    page_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    driver.set_window_size(1920, page_height)
    driver.save_screenshot(id + '.png')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

参考記事書いたものです。

①
ローカルに別途ダウンロードしたchromedriver.exeを使えば動きます。

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

を

```
cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exeへのパス')
```

に変えれば動きます。
PATHが通っている場所にchromedriver.exeを置けば、カッコの中は空でOKです。

②
Anaconda Promptから、参考記事の通り

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

すればインストールできます。
Anaconda登録済みのパッケージの中には、webdriver_managerは無いはずです。

Comment: まさかのご本人様登場。ありがとうございます。

ご指摘いただいたように、下記でうまく動くようになりました。


cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exeへのパス')